# Electron returns empty NativeImage when I'm trying to read image from clipboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I write default code from documentaion of Electron, but electron returns empty NativeImage object.

```
  const { clipboard } = require("electron")
  console.log(clipboard.readImage("clipboard"))
```

What should I do to paste image from clipboard?

Comment: Maybe there is no image on clipboard (for example it is text).

Comment: No, that's definitely not. Other apps like Discord see the image

Comment: `Currently PNG and JPEG image formats are supported` is this your case? https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#nativeimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it seems that `console.log` always display a `NativeImage` *empty* object, whether there is an image in the clipboard or not.

Try to go a step further and convert the `NativeImage` object to a data URL string, for instance; also, you should be able to check if the clipboard contains an image beforehand by using the `clipboard.availableFormats` method.

The following code snippet works for me on macOS:

```
const { clipboard } = require("electron");

let availableFormats = clipboard.availableFormats("clipboard");
if (availableFormats.includes("image/png") || availableFormats.includes("image/jpeg"))
{
    console.log(clipboard.readImage("clipboard").toDataURL());
}
else
{
    console.log("No image in clipboard");
}
```